# Sieve of Eratosthenes Refinement

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

From Wikipedia:

> 1. Create a list of consecutive integers from $2$ through $n$: $(2, 3, 4, ..., n)$.
> 2. Initially, let $p$ equal $2$, the smallest prime number.
> 3. Starting from $2p$, enumerate the multiples of $p$ by counting to $n$ in increments of $p$, and mark them in the list (these will be $2p$, $3p$, $4p$, ... ; the $p$ itself should not be marked).
> 4. Find the first number greater than $p$ in the list that is not marked. If there was no such number, stop. Otherwise, let $p$ now equal this new number (which is the next prime), and repeat from step $3$.

I understand all of the above except for the following refinement to the algorithm:

**As a refinement, it is sufficient to mark the numbers in step 3 starting from $p^2$, as all the smaller multiples of $p$ will have already been marked at that point**

Why is this the case? How can I be sure that they will have been marked? Could someone help me prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A composite number $n$ must have a prime factor less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$.  This means that any composite less than $p^2$ has a prime factor less than $p$, and hence has already been crossed out by the time you are sieving with $p$.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example? I'm getting a bit lost, sorry if this sounds stupid

Comment: For instance the first new number crossed out when sieving with $5$ would be $5^2=25$, since all the smaller composite multiples of $5$ each have a prime factor less than $5$ that already got them crossed out.  $10$ was crossed out by $2$; and $15$ by $3$; and $20$ by $2$.

Comment: They get crossed out because these smaller composite multiples can always be written as a product of those  prime factors less than 5 correct?

Comment: Right.  For composites less than $p^2$, there must be a nontrivial factor (i.e. greater than 1) that is less than $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Those are multiples $k\, p < p^2$ thus $k < p$ and the multiples of $k$, thus $k' \, k$, should have been marked already, including $k' = p$ if $p\, k \le n$. As now $k\, p \le n$ this should be the case.